# Gnosis Safe adding a delegate using Ledger owner using MetaMask

Tags: gnosis-safe, ledger-nano-s

Gnosis Safe adding a delegate using MetaMask.

We can add delegate by using Gnosis Safe owners private keys by following the steps as mentioned in https://github.com/gnosis/safe-docs/blob/devportal/docs/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate.md

However, we do not want to extract the private keys from the hardware ledger wallet to create a delegate.

I was working on writing a script to sign the delegate using MetaMask.
Here is code : https://github.com/virendrapatidar/multisig-delegator
This works fine if Gnosis safe owner is the software wallet.
However, it does not work if the owner is a ledger hardware wallet and sign by ledger hardware wallet using Metamask. The error is "Signature does not match provided delegator=xxxxx"

Any input will help.

Answer (score 1):

Badger finance created a bounty on this before. A dapp that demonstrates how to allow Gnosis-Safe delegation through Metamask or Ledger, without revealing users' private key. Here's the winning submission.

Demo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jxe_1COHHk
Dapp repo - https://github.com/Soptq/gnosis-safe-delegate-dapp

Worth checking out how this repo handles the signatures.

Edit - found where the dapp is deployed! - https://gnosis-delegator.badger.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I checked the solution late and wrote a simple script.
Details here.
https://github.com/virendrapatidar/multisig-delegator